# Why is it possible to compare integer and string without converting?

Tags: string, vb.net, integer

I'm comparing integer and string in vb. Please check the following code:

```
Dim strPrice as String = "9"
If CInt(Int(txtPrice.Text)) < strPrice Then 
    Return False 
End If
```

Is it possible to compare without converting both of them to integer? 
When I run this code, it doesn't cause any errors. I just want to know why this is possible?

Comment: It is literally impossible to compare two objects of different types. Even if you have `Option Strict Off` and write code that appears to do so, there will still be a conversion performed behind the scenes at run-time. The problem is that it may not be the one you want in that case, which is why you should ALWAYS be explicit. In short, no it is not possible.

Comment: In your case, there are issues with that code. For one thing, why `Int` and `CInt`? Secondly, why convert one `String` to an `Integer` and not the other? Thirdly, what if the user enters text that doesn't represent a number, or no text at all?

Comment: To be clear, you start with two `Strings` so you could just compare them directly because they are the same type. The problem is, "10" is considered to be less than "2" because `Strings are compared alphabetically, not numerically.  If you want a numeric comparison then you have to compare numbers.

Comment: Yes, by converting Integer to String ;)

Comment: @jmcilhinney First, (Int) is object, so I convert to Integer with (CInt). Second, I'm just curious and do this on purpose. Third, I won't let type any character.

Comment: Buy why call `Int` in the first place when `CInt` can convert a `String` to an `Integer`? The purpose of `Int` is to return the `Integer` portion of a number. What's the point of that in this case?  Even if that is your aim, we're not in VB6 any more so `Math.Truncate` or `Math.Floor` would be the appropriate option.

Comment: As has already been said, the code provided will work in some cases but the reason it is bad practice is that it won't work in all cases. I've told you what cases it won't work in.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney I have no idea. And actually, that's not my code. I need to check that code and want to know why that code running correctly.

Comment: It works in some cases because `Option Strict Off` allows implicit conversions, i.e. the system will convert one of the values to the same type as the other in order to compare like with like even if your code doesn't do so explicitly. I already said that. With `Option Strict On`, that code would not compile. `Option Strict` should always be `On`. Hint: now is the time that you should make the effort to learn about `Option Strict`. Even if the code compiles, it will still crash your app under certain circumstances. Well-written code won't do that.

Comment: The reason why this compare is possible is that you do not have `Option Strict On`. Turn that option on to make sure that code like this will not compile.

Comment: I already turn that option on but still compile well and running correctly. @Blackwood

Comment: I suspect you don't have `Option Strict On` in effect for this file. If you did, the `strPrice` in the `If` statement would be flagged with "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Double'. Try adding `Option Strict On` as the first line in the file.

Comment: @Blackwood Ohh, I got it. Thank you so much. Your answer is really helpful to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

You can turn off `Option Strict` and the code will compile, execute, and probably even produce the correct result... but it **still** converted the string to an integer to make the comparison. You just didn't have to write the `CInt()` operation yourself.

Moreover, this is *not good practice.* Maybe you get things correct this time, but ultimately it leads to type errors that **will** show up at runtime that you would have avoided otherwise.

Comment: I just want to prove this code is incorrect but I have no idea how to run this code to occur error.

Comment: @Yuki, firstly, you didn't say that in your actual question, so maybe you ought to think about providing ALL the relevant information in future. Secondly, I've already told you how to generate an exception: "what if the user enters text that doesn't represent a number, or no text at all".

Comment: @ jmcilhinney Sorry for my bad explanation and Thank you for your commenting. so in this case, if I won't let any text or character except number then it will not occur error, Am I right?

Comment: Why are you asking whether you're right when you can simply test it for yourself? We're here to help with stuff you can't work out, not stuff that you can't be bothered to work out. If you have code then you can execute and see what happens for yourself, so you don't need to ask us.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm so sorry and thank you for your answer. I won't do that kind of question again. I'm deeply sorry.

Comment: We are here to help but you do need to do your part first. Always ask "what can I do for myself" before posting questions. If you can test code or read documentation then always do that first.  You'll find that you can solve many of your own issues and also discover things that you weren't looking for.  We'll be here to help with the rest.